# Visual calendar for streaks and states

Tags: calendar

I am looking for a visual calendar that lets me see several streaks at a time as well as events in several categories, per day, preferably color-coded.

I am currently using an on-the-wall calendar to track my streaks for different tasks (such as for instance writing code, running or going to bed on time). Each of them is represented as a lane of a different color, at a different height.

As of now, I am looking to replace that calendar with an app that would be doing the same, but there are so many calendar apps I am having trouble finding what I need.

I don't really care if it's an iOS app, web app or Windows app - all of them are fine for me as long as I can get an overview in a single glance.